# Как можно получить полный путь к файлу в bat?

Tags: cmd, bat, path

Есть такая проблема. В bat-файле мне нужно вывести путь до какого-либо файла: либо из текущей директории, либо файла из Path. В принципе, у меня все работает, но скрипт ломается, когда в Path записан относительный путь.
Например:
вот Path: "a;C:\dev". В обеих этих папках есть файл 1.ехе. Мой скрипт выведет такой результат:

```
C:\\dev\1.exe
a\1.exe
```

а мне нужно, чтобы во второй строчке был полный путь к файлу. Я знаю, что есть модификаторы типа %~dp1, но если имя файла состоит из нескольких слов, то использовать такую конструкцию я не могу, так как %~dp* не работает.
В общем, суть вопроса: как получить полный путь к файлу в bat?

Comment: Переменная окружения `%PATH%` описывает все каталоги, где следует искать исполнимый файл. И в практике использования значений этой переменной обычно задается полный, а не относительный путь. Ваша задача: перечислить все подходящие `exe`-файлы в данных каталогах, найти путь именно к тому файлу, который будет вызван. или что-то другое? Может мы обсуждаем разные переменные `PATH`?

Comment: Именно, что в процессе работы другой программы в `PATH` может добавиться относительный путь, поэтому нужно проверить и их тоже. Команду `where` использовать нельзя

Comment: Ну давайте обсудим, относительно чего следует читать относительный путь: относительно каждого значения (разделенного точкой-запятой) переменной `%PATH%`, относительно `%SYSTEMROOT%`,относительно `%WINDIR%`, относительно `%SYSTEMDRIVE%` или др. ? То есть количество каталогов для поиска может резко увеличиться, а правил описывающих этот процесс - нет. Полагаю, поэтому относительные пути в %PATH% и не используются. Зачем менять переменную системного окружение, если значение можно записать в реестр, в текстовый файл или, как следовало бы, в отдельно созданную переменную системного окружения?

Comment: Программа должна искать какой-то файл, но не только в текущем каталоге, в `PATH`, но и в подкаталогах. Для этого программа добавляет в текущей сессии командной строки в переменную `PATH` относительный путь. Проблема такая, что я не могу понять, как мне вывести путь до файла, а не аргумент, который ввел пользователь, но с полным путем

Comment: Вы так и не ответили, в каких хотите подкаталогах искать.

Comment: в тех, которые добавили. То есть если `PATH=a\;C:\dev\ `, то в `%cd%\a\ ` и `C:\dev\ `

Comment: тогда рекомендую разбить обработку переменной PATH в цикле (используя как разделитель символ `;`) и там же проверять на существование файла `IF EXIST`. Примеры того, разбить строку на переменные хорошо написаны [здесь](https://exceptionshub.com/how-to-split-a-string-in-a-windows-batch-file-3.html). В том случае, если переменная цикла является относительным путем, начинается с символа  \ , то проверку проводить с добавлением спереди переменной `%CD%.`